# How to update a variable in controller (ControllerAs syntax) from directive in Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controlleras

I have a `dropzone` directive:

```
function dropzone() {
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

            var config = {
                url: 'http://192.168.1.114:8080/api/files',
                maxFilesize: 100,
                paramName: "file",
                maxThumbnailFilesize: 10,
                parallelUploads: 1,
                autoProcessQueue: true
            };

            var eventHandlers = {
                 'success': function (file, response) {
                }

            };

            dropzone = new Dropzone(element[0], config);

            angular.forEach(eventHandlers, function(handler, event) {
                dropzone.on(event, handler);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Where the `response` in `success` event handlers is the uploaded file id.

I'd like to keep a list of ids of all uploaded files in my `uploadFileFormCtrl`:

```
function uploadFileFormCtrl() {
    var _this = this;

    _this.fileIds = [];
};
```

This will work for a specific controller, i.e. `uploadFileFormCtrl as uploadFile`

```
                'success': function (file, response) {
                    scope.uploadFile.fileIds.push(Number(response));
                    scope.$apply();
                }
```

However I have multiple different `controllers` (for example: `uploadFile`, `uploadImage`, etc) which have the `dropzone` file uploader, so I can't add a specific controller name in the directive.

How should the directive and the controller communicate with each other to achieve this?

Comment: you need an isolated scope for the directive, so that you can have multiples on a page, and then you need to pass the parameters from the controller in to the directive.

Comment: @Claies Is this what you mean: `scope: {formCtrl: '='}`, `scope.formCtrl.fileIds.push(Number(response));` and add `form-ctrl="uploadFile"` in the HTML?